# Angular. Не отображается вложенный массив в темплейте

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

Всем привет. 
После Vue решил 'пощупать Angular', но он пощупал меня.

Есть такой объект JSON, который я преобразую в объект при помощи HttpClientModule.

Собственно ниже - то как выводится полученный объект через консольку:

```
someObj: [   
{
    name: 'Thor', 
    friends: [
        {
            name: 'Loki'
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Doctor Who'
        }, 
        {
            name: 'Onotole'
        }
    ]
},
{
    name: 'Onotole', 
    friends: null
},
{
    name: 'Chubakka',
    friends: [
        {
            name: 'Darth Veider'
        }
    ]

}]
```

Те объект не пустой, и все ок.

Пытаюсь вывести список на страницу:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of something.someObj; let i = index;">
  <div>{{ item?.name }} {{ i }}</div>     
  <div *ngFor="let some of item?.friends">
    {{ some?.name }}
  </div>
 </div>
```

Но выводится только лишь:

Thor 0
Onotole 1
Chubakka 2

При это в консоли ошибок нету.
Что я делаю не так?

Структуры:

```
 export class Something { 
         someobj: SomeObj[]; 
 } 

 export class SomeObj{ 
         name: string; 
         friends: Friends[]; 
 } 

export class Friends{ 
         name: string; 
}
```

Инициализация:

```
something: Something;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this.http.get('assets/something.json').subscribe((data: Something) => 
          {this.something = data; console.log(this.something)});
  }
```

Comment: что бы вывести `friends` вам нужно обращаться в `item?.friends.name` я с angular не силен но в angularJS точно так

Comment: вы итерируете свойство `about` - где оно?

Comment: где класс описания компоненты? в студию пожалуйста

Comment: about да, неправильно вписал.

Comment: @Санаев  

export class Something {
    someobj: SomeObj[];
}    

export class SomeObj{
    name: string;
    friends: Friends[];
}

export class Friends{
    name: string;
}

Comment: @VOV обновите вопрос

Comment: @Санаев готово, обновил

Comment: покажите настоящий шаблон, вы итерируете объект `someObj`, но его нету в компоненте, либо же вы пишите `something.someObj`?

Comment: У вас ошибка . Some возвращает массив name а не один Нейм

Comment: @overthesanity вы правы, something.someObj (добавил в код в вопросе)

Comment: @Санаев, что ? он итерирует массив `friends`, где `some` на каждой итерации объект со свойством `name`, `some` ничего не возвращает

Comment: @overthesanity внимательно посмотрите на структуру Json!

Comment: @Санаев, посмотрел, я вижу массив `friends` внутри которого объекты со свойством `name`, где там массив нейм?

Comment: @Санаев  Что то я еще сильнее запутался...

Comment: @overthesanity упс вы правы . Я сонный уже просто]

Comment: @Санаев  напишите, пожалуйста, цикл. Я добавил еще один, но у меня так ничего и не отобразилось.. Никак не могу ошибку понять

Comment: @vov уберите его. У вас все правильно . Возможно просто данные не приходят

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы неправильно обращаетесь к свойству, если свойство содержит дефис - то нужно обращаться к свойству через квадратные скобки (`['some-property']`). Angular на такие вещи не кидает эксепшены, потому что компилятор компилирует конструкцию `*ngFor="let item of data.some-property"` в `context.$implicit.some - componentInstance.property`, что является математической операцией, результатом которой будет - `object - undefined = NaN`, далее директива `ngFor` проверяет является ли `@Input` свойство массивом и итерирует его, а `Array.isArray(NaN) => false`.